# How to force installation of extension during module install

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, module, extension

When installing a module how do you require it's extension to be installed at the same time and vice versa?

I did a google search and looked over the docs as well and didn't find anything. That doesn't mean it's not out there. Maybe I wasn't searching for the right terms.

[image]

Comment: Which add-on is that?

Comment: That's Backup Pro. And I'm now seeing exactly what Derek is describing in his answer that came up as I was writing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of an undocumented feature, but it works like this.

In your extension, add a class variable called `$required_by`, with an array of values:

```
$required_by = array('module');
```

('module' is actually the only acceptable array value here, as neither plugins nor accessories have installation routines, which are needed for this to work.)

Note that this *does not automatically install* (or later, uninstall) your extension. It just makes it clear that you can't install one without the other.

So your module's `install()` method must *also* install your extension (basically, everything you'd normally have in your extension's `activate_extension()` method). Likewise, your module's `uninstall()` method must contain everything your extension's `disable_extension()`  method would normally have.

(These methods in your extension in this case should just `return true`.)

Have a look at the bundled Safecracker package for a good example.